# Print bash command result in Gtk Textview

Tags: python, bash, gtk

I want to print the file attributes using bash command and write result in Textview.
Here path is selected through select button.File path is stored in text.
os.system("stat"+text+"") prints on terminals.I want to store the result of this command.

```css
#/usr/bin/python
import pygtk,gtk,os

class project:
  def enter_callback(self,widget,entry):
    entry_text=entry.get_text()
    print("entry contents: %s \n" % entry_text)
    
  def file_ok_sel(self,w):
    print("%s " % self.filew.get_filename())
    text=self.filew.get_filename()
    print(text)    
    os.system("stat " + text + "") 
    
  def button1_select(self,widget,data=None):
    self.filew=gtk.FileSelection("File selection")
    self.filew.connect("destroy",self.destroy)
    self.filew.ok_button.connect("clicked",self.file_ok_sel)
    self.filew.cancel_button.connect("clicked",lambda w:self.filew.destroy())
    self.filew.set_filename("penguin.png")
    self.filew.show()
    
  def destroy(self,widget):
    print("quit")    
  
  def __init__(self):
    self.window=gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.set_title("printing")
    self.window.connect("delete_event",lambda a1,a2:gtk.main_quit())
    self.window.set_border_width(20)      
    vbox=gtk.VBox(True,2)
    self.window.add(vbox)  
    
    label=gtk.Label("Select File")
    label.set_alignment(0,0)
    vbox.pack_start(label,False,False,0)
    label.show()
    
   #adding TEXTVIEW to print bash command result
    textview = gtk.TextView()
    textbuffer = textview.get_buffer()
    self.window.add(textview)
    
    vbox.pack_start(textview,True,True,0)
    textview.show()
    vbox.show()
    self.window.show()
    
    #Button used to select FILE
    button=gtk.Button("select")
    button.connect("clicked",self.button1_select,"select 1")    
    vbox.pack_start(button,True,True,2)
    button.show()
    
def main():
  gtk.main()
  return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
  project()
  main()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `init` add

`self.textbuffer = textview.get_buffer()`

Then when you want to update it, do:

```
self.result = os.system("stat"+text+"")
self.textbuffer.set_text(self.result)`
```

Comment: I want to use that result in TextViev widget.How can I do that?

Comment: Update the buffer for textview

Comment: See answer, you use .set_text() on the text_buffer

Comment: Where i put this code,i put it in method file_ok_sel,it gives AttributeError: project instance has no attribute 'textbuffer'.

Comment: You need to create the variable in init(), I updated explaining it better